# Huge amount of data want to display in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have read huge amount of data ,  Using Tcp connection and i want to display that data in iphone .

One important thing is , iphone will not hangs at any time  .

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you should consider to use SQLite to store your data locally and present it from the local storage. This way your application will not hang...

Comment: Its a live data , i dont want to store it just displayed what ever comes over tcp connections. No delays should occur in my application,   for that i store data in sqlite db and retrived data from the local means its get some time delay in my application.

Comment: If you have to parse the data and then display then libxml2 is good option and also use UINib in case for uitableviewcell if you are using a uitableview considering memory issues .

Comment: Can you send some code to understand it ? and also i didnt use UINib what it is ?